How to correctly apply KKT conditions to this specific problem?
I want to solve the following optimization problem:
\begin{align*}
\max a_4 \text{ s.t. } a_1^2 + 2a_1 + a_2^2 + 2a_2 + a_3^2 + 2a_2 + a_4^2 -2a_4 = 0 
\end{align*}
I know that every optimal point satisfies the KKT-conditions. Applied to this problem this yields
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix} 
0\\0\\0\\1
\end{pmatrix} + \lambda \begin{pmatrix} a_1 + 2 \\ a_2 + 2 \\ a_3+2 \\ a_4-2 \end{pmatrix} = 0 \\
a_1^2 + 2a_1 + a_2^2 + 2a_2 + a_3^2 + 2a_2 + a_4^2 -2a_4 = 0 
\end{align*}
Since $\lambda$ cannot be $0$ because of the fourth equation, we obtain $a_1 = -2, a_2 = -2, a_3=-2$. Plugging this in the system reduces to
\begin{align*}
1 + \lambda (a_4-2) = 0 \\
a_4(a_4-2) = 0 
\end{align*}
Which has a unique solution of $a_4 = 0$ and $\lambda = 0.5$.
Therefore every optimal point needs to satisfy $a_1 = -2, a_2 = -2, a_3=-2, a_4=0$ with a maximum value of $0$.
But I think somewhere my conclusions are wrong since for example the point $a_1 = -1 - 1/\sqrt{3}, a_2 = -1 + \sqrt{3}, a_3 = -1 - 1/\sqrt{3}, a_4 = 1+1/\sqrt{3}$ satisfies \begin{align*} a_1^2 + 2a_1 + a_2^2 + 2a_2 + a_3^2 + 2a_2 + a_4^2 -2a_4 = 0 \end{align*} and has a higher optimal value of $1 + 1/\sqrt{3}$.
Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

I think $(-1,-1,-1,3)$ is the optimal.

Hi @Bob Dobbs thank you very much for your answer. In my understanding this points also does not satisfy KKT conditions (in my probably wrong definition). How did you come up with it?

Your derivative of the constraint (let's call it $g$) seems to be off. For example $\partial_{a_1} g(a) = 2a_1+2$

@samabu Yes, derivative mistakes, NN2 was quicker.

The error is here
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
0\\0\\0\\1
\end{pmatrix} + \lambda \begin{pmatrix} a_1 + 2 \\ a_2 + 2 \\ a_3+2 \\ a_4-2 \end{pmatrix} = 0 $$
in fact $(x^2 +2x)' = 2(x+1)$, not $x+2$.
And the derivative must be
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
0\\0\\0\\1
\end{pmatrix} +2 \lambda \begin{pmatrix} a_1 + 1 \\ a_2 + 1 \\ a_3+1 \\ a_4-1 \end{pmatrix} = 0  \tag{1}$$
Solve $(1)$ and the constraint $(a_1 +1)^2 + (a_2 +1)^2 + (a_3 +1)^2 + (a_4 -1)^2  = 4$, you obtain $$\color{red}{(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,\lambda) = \left(-1,-1,-1,3,-\frac{1}{4}\right)}$$

Yes, you are absolutely right! Thank you!
